# Wordpress user input security

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have written a Wordpress php template to take user input via a HTML form. The information in the form is used to create a new (draft) post. I have escaped all the input using.

```
esc_html($_POST['name']);
```

I also check user input is present before submit. How do I protect against sql injection? Are there another precautions I should take.

Comment: Hi @user, welcome to SO. This seems like a very google-able question and probably has a duplicate on this very site :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the built in functions (such as `wp_insert_post`) for creating the post then you don't need to worry about SQL injections; WordPress escapes the content before inserting into the database.

If you are running any additional queries, make sure you use `$wpdb->prepare()` to bind your parameters. The escaping will be taken care of for you.

You should read this article:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Database

You should also look into adding a nonce to your form:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field